# Using std::find with user supplied predicate - homemade find() overload

Tags: c++

I have a class which is essentially a `std::vector<T>` with some additional functionality. The class has `find(const T& value )` method which will return index of first occurence of `value` or -1:

```
int my::find(const T& value) {
    auto iter = std::find(this->data.begin(), this->data.end(), value);
    if (iter == this->data.end())
        return -1;

    return std::distance(this->data.begin(), iter);
}
```

all good. I then wanted to create a `find()` overload which took in a arbitrary predicate instead of a value - I have tried:

```
int my::find(const std::function<bool(const T&)>& pred) {
    auto iter = std::find(this->data.begin(), this->data.end(), pred);
    ...
}
```

and also:

```
template <typename P>
int my::find(P&& pred) {
    auto iter = ...
}
```

But both cases fail to compile because "the compiler" tries to find `pred` in a vector of `pred` type values, instead of applying `pred` to the values, i.e. when when I have instantiated `my<int>` I get compiler errors like:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘const std::function<bool(const int&)>’)
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm `std::find` will always treat its third argument as a value that is compared to elements in the given sequence by `operator==`. The predicate you pass in can't be compared to the `T` instances of the class, hence the compiler error.

You are looking for [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (overloads #3-4), which takes a predicate as the third argument.

Comment: phew, I vote that cppreference restart their ordinals when they hit a differently-named overload (find overload 1, find overload 2, find_if overload 1, find_if overload 2 ...)

Answer (score 5):

When you use a predicate, use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
int my::find(const std::function<bool(const T&)>& pred) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(this->data.begin(), this->data.end(), pred);
    ...
}
```

In keeping with function names in the standard library, I think you should change your function name also to `find_if` when you use a predicate.

```
int my::find_if(const std::function<bool(const T&)>& pred) {
    auto iter = std::find_if(this->data.begin(), this->data.end(), pred);
    ...
}
```